# Adding What's this button

Tags: c++, qt

How can i add what's this button besides close button, i have seen lot of threads where they want to remove it, but not a single thread where they want to add it. From couple of threads they mentioned it was default, well it isn't default in mine and I am using windows.
This is how my title bar looks. [image: Title bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the help button which comes by default for `QDialog`. You can get the help button on a main window by using this code for the window flags:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

Note that you will be missing out the maximize and  the minimize buttons when you do this. According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP cannot be used with the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX or WS_MINIMIZEBOX styles.

These are the underlying windows system flags for `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint`, `Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint` and `Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint`.

Comment: I was ok with missing out on max and min, but even close button doesnt work.

Comment: @user5603723 : I just missed a flag in the answer. Please check the update.