# Is Qt "what's this" button cross-platform?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, qt4, titlebar

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653917/adding-whats-this-button) the *what's this* button should be present by default in the title bar of every QDialog, at least on Microsoft Windows.

When I test in Debian 9 with KDE I can see the button (the "?" on the right):
[image]

When I test in Debian 9 with Gnome 3 I cannot see the button:
[image]

I have not found anywhere the indication that this button is cross-platform (nor which platforms are compatible).

I would like to know:

- can it be made to work on Gnome 3 ? (do I have to change a Gnome 3 setting ?)
- does it works on Windows 7 and 10 ?
- does it works on recent macOs versions ?

I am using Qt 4.8.7 but I am also interested in Qt 5

Comment: Have you tried explicitly enabling it via the `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` (+ `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint`) flag(s)? It does work on any windows, but no clue about macos or gnome

Comment: I also tried that and it did not help, but then I checked what the default flags were (`this->windowFlags()`) and saw that `Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint` was already enabled. I also tried settings the flags before/after `this->setupUi()` but that did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer for "is it cross platform?": not really... There is probably a way to get it to work, but it's not going to be as simple as on Windows.

I have experienced weird quirks with Qt in Linux environments due to the window manager.

I know that in Qt5, a lot of the quirks I experienced in Linux environments while using Qt4 have been addressed, however, I am running Qt5 on Ubuntu 18.07 and when I launched a QDialog with (and without) the flags set, the What's This button did not show up for me either.

When I compile and run the same code (without setting the windows flags) on Windows, the What's This button did show up.

Here my system info:

- Windows 7 Qt 5.6.1
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Qt 5.9.5

I can edit this post later about whether or not it works with Windows 10, although I would assume it does.
Unfortunately, I don't have access to macOS to answer your question about how it works there.

On a somewhat related note, if you have the ability to upgrade to Qt5, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In the end I chosed to enable the ["Help" button](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#ButtonRole-enum) and to use it to enter the **what's this** mode. I could refine my solution by hiding the button on Windows and KDE (because there is already the **?** button in the titlebar). Note: the position of this button is OS dependant (just like the position of **Ok** and **Cancel** buttons are so that should not be a problem for you.

Comment: (continued) I changed the text of this button to be **?** to match the button in the title bar when existing. The problem of this solution is that I suppose only one Help button can be created so I may have to craft a button if I want to add another button that open the full *"F1"* help.